# Cloned a PC to a USB-stick for Virtual PC, extremely slow

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

We have an old PC we want to get rid of, but it has some applications/setup we might need access every now and then.

**What I did:**

I thought making it into a Virtual PC was a good idea. And since we probably only will use it a few times a year (if any at all), I thought storing it on a USB-drive was a good idea.

So I used sysinternals "Disk2vhd" to clone the harddrive into a .vhdx file, and I put that file onto a USB stick.

I then used Microsoft Hyper-V to create a virtual machine, and selected the vhdx file as the harddrive.

**The problem:**

The PC booted but it was extremely slow. I'm talking 10 minutes booting, and when booted it's completely unusable. Unresponsible, I have not even managed to get the start-menu show up after clicking on it, and it takes a literal minute from I click on an icon to it's selected.

I really don't understand why it's this unresponsible? The USB stick read/write rate is 250/100 MB/S, but  I guess the USB-port will not be close to that.

But even at 10MB/s, shouldn't the Virtual PC be perfectly usable?  It bahaves how I would expect if I was running from a floppy disk.

**Anyone have any idea what's wrong, or other suggestions on how to do what I want?**

**Edit:** I ran a speed test on the USB-stick, a Corsair Flash Voyager GT 64GB, and the WRITE IOPS is just ridiculously low - is this normal for a USB?

[image]

Comment: The performance issues are likely caused by the fact you are trying to run the VM off a USB flash drive.

Comment: If you don't use it very often, would it be OK to copy it onto the internal drive, run it, then copy it back to the stick? You probably won't get many [IOPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOPS) from a USB stick.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Look at the edit, I guess that solves the question. I guess I might as well just get an USB-enclosure for an old harddrive, if USB-sticks are this useless...

Comment: USB sticks hate reading & writing at the same time & are many factors worse on lots of small writes. Your figures don't surprise me. You'd probably do significantly better with a small SSD, so long as it's not more than half full.

Comment: A USB 3.2 Gen 2 SSD would probably work.  There is a reason Microsoft barely supported and now discontinued Windows To Go support

Answer (score 0):

Tips:

Make sure there is a reasonable amount of memory allocated (for the VM) for running the application + some more.

If there is a pagefile in use in the VM - move it away from the USB-drive
(e.g. create a *.vhd on the local HD).
( Control panel > System > /Advanced\ > Performance > [settings] > Virtual Memory )